# createButton OpenCV new Qt functionality

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, opencv, button

When I try to compile this it gives me an

> Unhandled exception at 0x75B0C42D in Example7.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0016F9EC.

I don't know what else to try. I've tried it so many different ways and looked all around and I don't seem to find anything that works for me.

I'm running OpenCV 2.4.11 Visual Studio 2013 all in x84 libraries windows 7 x64.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int state;

void callbackButton2(int state, void* userdata)
  {
     cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
  }

int main()
 {
   Mat image;
    image =        imread("C:/Users/anjamaco/Documents/OPENCV/CODE/1/Example1/Capture2.PNG",1);   // Read the fi

if (!image.data)                              // Check for invalid input
{
    cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
namedWindow("Control Panel", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE | CV_GUI_NORMAL);

createButton("Dummy button", callbackButton2, NULL, CV_PUSH_BUTTON, 1);


imshow("Display window", image);                   // Show our image inside it.

waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
return 0;
 }
```

Could someone please give me an example on how to implement a button that shows text on the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function only works if you built OpenCV with **QT support**. OpenCV doesn't come with this feature by default.

On my Windows 8 box with MSVC 2013 I can see the following message printed to the console along with the crash:

> OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (The library is compiled without QT support) in cv::createButton, file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 478

Comment: I tried the link that the opencv tutorial gives [http://qt.nokia.com/downloads](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads) but looks like no worky would this work [https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2)

Comment: Yes. Just download the one that is compatible with your Visual Studio version.